# Proving a result in infinite products: $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges (to a non zero element) iff the series $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

We assume that $\sum |a_n|^{2}$ converges, then I want to conclude that $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges to a **non zero element** $\iff$ the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

---

> **My attempt**

If $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges to a non zero element then we can write

$$\prod (1+a_n)= \prod \exp(\ln(1+a_n))= \exp(\sum \ln (1+a_n)) \le \exp(\sum |\ln (1+a_n)|)$$

Then using that $\sum |a_n|^{2}$ converges we can choose $n$ such that $|a_n|^2 < \frac{1}{4}$ and we know that $|ln(1+z)|\le 2 |z|$ if $|z|< \frac{1}{2}$ using the series expansion, we get that

$$\exp(\sum |\ln (1+a_n)|) \le \exp(\sum 2|a_n|)$$

For the converse I want to use the result that says that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges then $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges so since we have that $\sum |a_n|^{2}$ converges then $\sum |a_n|$ converges and  $\prod (1+a_n)$ does too.

---

> **Questions**

But from here I don't know if I am right, how to conclude and solve the converse part to say that we have a non zero limit, and another thing Can someone provide explicit examples of a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that  $\sum a_n$ converges but $\prod (1+a_n)$ diverges and the other way around (This is $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges but $\sum a_n$ diverges )?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The product $\prod (1 + a_n)$ and the series $\sum a_n$ must converge or diverge together when $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, but only for the separate cases where $a_n \geqslant 0$ and $-1 < a_n < 0$ for all $n$. If $a_n$ changes sign periodically you can find cases where  the product and series are not simultaneously convergent (even when the terms are real).  For examples see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679365/148510

Comment: Let me check your reference but could you provide a detailed proof of the other facts ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349713/suma-n2-infty-and-sum-a-n-infty-implies-sum-log1a-n-converges

Comment: Let me check it just a moment, Can I let you know if there is something missing or questions ?

Comment: @RRL How do you cocnlude that you don't have a zero limit in the product?

Answer (score 6):

If $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges, then $|a_n| \to 0$ and there is a positive integer $N$ such that  $|a_n| < 1/2$ for all $n > N$.

We then have

$$| \log(1 + a_n) - a_n| = \left|\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{a_n^k}{k} \right| \leqslant \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{|a_n|^k}{k}  \leqslant \frac1{2}|a_n|^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_n|^k \\ = \frac{|a_n|^2}{2(1 - |a_n|)}  < |a_n|^2   $$

Hence, the series $\sum (\log(1+a_n) - a_n)$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ converge or diverge together , which implies that $\sum a_n$ and $\prod (1+a_n)$ converge or diverge together

Comment: Let me check it but this proves both sides right ?

Comment: It does prove both sides. For your converse use $\sum \log (1 + a_n) = \sum ( \log( 1+ a_n) - a_n) + \sum a_n$. Then convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum \log(1 + a_n)$,  since both series on the RHS converge,

Comment: ... and the other implication follows from  $\sum a_n = \sum ( \log( 1+ a_n) - a_n) - \sum  \log( 1+ a_n)$

Comment: How do you conclude that is a non-zero limit (in the product)?

Comment: The product has a zero limit if and only if $\sum \log(1 + a_n)$ diverges to $- \infty$.  So if $\sum a_n$ is convergent that will not happen.

Comment: Also the product could be zero if for one of the terms $a_n = -1$. If this occurs for finitely many $n$ then you have a degenerate case and you consider what happens to the product after the last point at which a term is zero. This is usually excluded in the hypotheses of the theorem.

Comment: Ok, but I didn't understand your last comment :)

Comment: I'm just excluding the trivial case where $\log(1 + a_n)$ is not defined. One hypothesis of this theorem should be $a_n > -1$ for all $n$.

Comment: aaa ok so you think that the problem is missing that condition? But I can argue as you did right, we know that we have a zero limit if the logarithm series diverges, then by your above proof we have that no and the product is well defined right?

Comment: Correct.  I'm sure the condition $a_n > -1$ is implicit. That is almost always stated up front but obviously without it, the product is zero or oscillatory.

Comment: @RRL I struggled with the above question (an excercise in Stein Shakarachi) for sometime and later proved it exactly the same way as you did, the main clever part with the proof is that we must consider $\log(1+a_n)-a_n$ instead of let us say $\log(1+a_n)$ to exploit the absolute convergence of $|a_n|^2$. Beautifully well written proof.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You've said that for small $x$, $\ln(1+x) < 2x$. That gave you an upper bound.

Can you make a similar claim, such as "for small enough $x$, $\ln(1 + x) > x/2$", for example? If so, you can reverse all your inequalities and do the lower bound proof.

I'm *not* saying that the bound I've suggested above is correct...merely that it *might* be, and you should try to prove it or find something similar that works.

Comment: Well I have found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234043/infinite-product-convergence-problem?rq=1 but I don't know if it is what we want :)

Comment: And what the examples and the converse part?

Comment: The point of suggesting a lower bound was to help with the converse part. For the examples: to find such a thing, you'd need a sequence where the sum of the squared moduli is NOT bounded. (Because if it IS bounded, then the two notions are equivalent, as you'll have just proved!) That might help you look for examples in the right places. Also: why do you think that there have to be examples for both directions? Perhaps under ALL conditions, we have one implication, but only under the bounded squared moduli sum condition do we have the other. If so, you should expect only one example.

Comment: Let me provide you a further result, just a second.

Comment: Ready I have edited my post so I hope that we have two examples.

Comment: Remember we are in complex analysis :) .