Convergence of $ a_N = \Pi_{n=1}^N \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}\right) $?
For $1\gg \varepsilon > 0$, does this following sequence converge to $0$?
$$
a_N = \Pi_{n=2}^N \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}\right)
$$
This is interesting, because if $\varepsilon = 0$, the product telescopes:
$$
\Pi_{n=2}^N \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \times \dots \times \frac{N-1}{N} = \frac{1}{N} \to 0.
$$
I'm wondering if we weaken the term $\frac{1}{n}$ by adding an $\varepsilon$ power, we still get convergence to $0$. If we let $\varepsilon = 1$, then we don't get this property.
$$
\Pi_{n=2}^N \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \frac{(1)(3)}{2^2} \times \dots \times \frac{(N-1)(N+1)}{N^2} \propto_{N} \frac{N-1}{N} \to 1.
$$
Edit: A comment indicates that there exists a relevant theorem. If so, I'd appreciate an answer or comment that links to or proves this theorem (just to verify that the theorem is correct and to get some interesting ideas out of the proof).

No, there is a theorem, for positive sequence $b_n<1$ that $\prod(1-b_n)$ converges  to a non-zero value iff $\sum b_n$ converges. So your product doesn't diverge for $\epsilon>0.$

@ThomasAndrews Would you have a source for this theorem?

I've forgotten the name of the theorem, if it has a name, so hard to look it up, but it isn't hard to use various inequalities about the logarithm to prove this, I believe.

Edit: A comment by @ThomasAndrews indicates that there exists a relevant theorem. If so, I'd appreciate an answer or comment that links to or proves this theorem (just to verify that the theorem is correct and to get some interesting ideas out of the proof).

Put your edit in the question, not in a comment. A reader shouldn't have to read all the comments to know your question.

The proper proof is to show the lemma $$\log(1-b)\geq - \frac{b}{1-b},$$ for $0<b<1.$ Then show $\frac 1{1-b_i}$ has a real upper bound if $\sum b_i$ converges and all $b_i\neq1.$

$$
a_N  = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^{1 + \varepsilon } }}} \right)} } \right) \le \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{n^{1 + \varepsilon } }}} } \right) \le \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{1 + \varepsilon } }}} } \right) <  + \infty
$$ since $\log(1-x)<-x$ for $0<x<1$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740706/proving-a-result-in-infinite-products-prod-1a-n-converges-to-a-non-zero?rq=1 for the theorem that Thomas Andrews mentioned. It's also mentioned on the Wiki page of infinite product
